# Parse a matrix and array of doubles to la4j object

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have experimented and I can't find a way to parse an array of Integers and a Matrix of doubles to a la4j matrice/vector object.

```
public void fillData(int[][] data2D, int height, int width) throws IOException{
    int[] data = initializeData(height, width);
    double [][] coordinates = initializeDataCoordinates(height, width);
    Matrix a = new Basic2DMatrix();

    int index1d = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < height; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < width; col++){
            int y = col+1;
            int x = row+1;
            //System.out.println("Current X: " + x);
            //System.out.println("Current Y: " + y);
            double xPow = Math.pow(x, 2);
            double yPow = Math.pow(y, 2);

            coordinates[row][0] = xPow*yPow;
            coordinates[row][1] = x*yPow;
            coordinates[row][2] = yPow;
            coordinates[row][3] = xPow*y;
            coordinates[row][4] = x*y;
            coordinates[row][5] = y;
            coordinates[row][6] = xPow;
            coordinates[row][7] = x;
            coordinates[row][8] = 1;

            a.add((double)data2D[row][col]);

            data[index1d] = data2D[row][col];
            index1d++;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I try to use the `add` method of the la4j lib but the matrice stays empty. My goal is to parse the whole content of `double[][] coordinates` and `int[] data` to la4j matrice and vector, respectivelly.

I have also tried parsing these to a CSV file but the scientific notation (due to extremely big numbers in my `coordinates` matrix) I can't parse it properly.

Any tips and ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the thing. First, you create `0x0` matrix with just call to the constructor `new Basic2DMatrix()`. Second, `matrix.add` is addition operation not insertion into the matrix (like matrix plus other matrix, or matrix plus value in your case). Calling `matrix.add(value)` adds given value to all the cells. In your case there is no cells in your matrix = nothing happened. All you need to do is call the constructor and pass the `coordinates` array there.

```
Matrix a = new Basic2DMatrix(coordinates); // easy-peasy
```

You can also use public access methods like `get`/`set` to manually set every element.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have found a way around this problem which was using Apache Math Commons matrix/vectors. I remember trying to use coordinates as a contructor parameter, but it didn't work, I am not sure why though.